# Convert Street Address to Business Name

Tags: android, reverse-geocoding, street-address

I'm doing research for an application and I want to be able to have a GPS coordinate and then find the owner or business name of that address.

I'm familiar with Android Geocoding and reverse Geocoding, but that only converts a coordinate to a street address.

The other alternative is doing web-scraping and querying it by the current coordinates, but it's hard to get perfect data this way and would like to know if anyone has been in this situation before.

Thanks